# When run terraform destroy in ecs aws, it removes a service first and then takes long time to remove tasks

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs, destroy

I have ECS service with 3 running tasks with linux docker container and light webservice. When I run `terraform destroy`, then it takes about 5-6 minutes to stop these tasks.

If stop them manually while it running, then it continues destroying other resources.

My question is: Is this expected time for destroying tasks? 
The whole process of destroying of a basic ECS cluster takes 8 minutes.

Logs from destroying Service with tasks:

```
2019-01-10T17:38:10 [DEBUG] module.ecs.aws_ecs_service.test-service: Still destroying... (ID: arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:xxxxxxxx:service/test-service, 10s elapsed)
2019-01-10T17:38:11 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v1.54.0_x4: 
2019-01-10T17:38:11 [DEBUG] Checking if ECS service arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:xxxxxxxx:service:service/test-service is INACTIVE
2019-01-10T17:38:11 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v1.54.0_x4: 2019-01-10T17:38:11 [DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] DEBUG: Request ecs/DescribeServices Details:
2019-01-10T17:38:11 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v1.54.0_x4: 2019/01/10 17:38:11 [DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] DEBUG: Response ecs/DescribeServices Details:
2019-01-10T17:38:11 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v1.54.0_x4: 2019/01/10 17:38:11 [DEBUG] ECS service (arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:xxxxxxxx:service/test-service) is currently "DRAINING"
2019-01-10T17:38:11 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v1.54.0_x4: 2019/01/10 17:38:11 [TRACE] Waiting 10s before next try
```

It's looping like that for about 6 minutes. If I go to AWS console, then I don't see a service but I see tasks with status "RUNNING" and if I manually STOP them, then destroy process continues to the next phase. You could try it with [this repo](https://github.com/telia-oss/terraform-aws-ecs-fargate), just make sure you have env variable `TF_LOG` set to at least `DEBUG`. In provided repo it will take less time, but you will see the same behavior.
Thanks for looking at this.

Comment: Can you show the output of `terraform destroy`?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I added some logs there

Comment: Even I got the same issue....Destroying service takes long time, not sure why

Comment: I believe it is because of defaulf behaviour of target-groups deregistration_delay. default time is 300 sec (5 min).  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html#deregistration-delay